# Java regex behaving wierd

Tags: java, regex

I have the below test case,

```
    @Test
    public void test_check_pattern_match_caseInSensitive_for_pre_sampling_filename() {
        // given
        String pattern = "Sample*.*Selection*.*Preliminary";

        // when

        // then
        assertThat(Util.checkPatternMatchCaseInSensitive(pattern, "Sample selectiossn preliminary"), is(false));
        assertThat(Util.checkPatternMatchCaseInSensitive(pattern, "sample selection preliminary"), is(true));
    }
```

The Util method is:

```
public static boolean checkPatternMatchCaseInSensitive(String pattern, String value) {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(value);
        if (matcher.find())
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Can someone please help, why the regex `Sample*.*Selection*.*Preliminary` matches the fileName = `Sample selectiossn preliminary` ?

This test case should pass, but it fails because of the first assert. :S

Comment: No it won't pass. [Check it here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Please run my code, you will know. The above test case fails.

Comment: change `*.*` to `.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` in regex means 0 or more of the previous character, while `.` means any single character.

What your expression is looking for is:

> 1. Exactly `Sampl`
> 2. 0 or more `e`
> 3. 0 or more of any char
> 4. Exactly `Selectio`
> 5. 0 or more `n`
> 6. 0 or more of any char
>      And so on

The problem would fall under points 5 and 6:

No `n` was found under point 5, and `ssn` would match point 6

Comment: Thanks, very nicely explained. All the other answers have been great too.

Answer (score 0):

- `Selection*` in regexp matches to `"selectio"`.
- `.*` matches to `"ssn "`
- `Preliminary` matches to `"preliminary"`

Regexp `n*` mean zero or more `n` character.

Regexp `.` mean any character.

Regexp `.*` mean zero or more any character.

Answer (score 0):

`*.*`

You have `"Selection*.*"`, which means `"Selectio"`, then any number (including zero) of letter `"n"`, then any number (including zero) of any character.

The match assumes zero matches of `"n"` matching `""`, and four matches of any character matching `"ssn "`.